# Долгое выполнение ресайза изображения при скроллинге RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `RecylerView` в который динамически добавляется по 10 объектов (`CardView`).
Каждый объект содержит `FrameLayout`, в который в свою очередь добавляется `LinearLayout`. `LinearLayout` может содержать до трех дочерних `LinearLayout` с `ImageView`. Часть функции формирования представлена ниже:

```
case 4:
    linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(activity);
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
            .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
    linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                    .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, Utils.pxToDp(5, activity), Utils.dpToPx(3, activity));
            postImageView = new PostImageView(activity, layoutParams);
            postImageView.setPlaceholder(post, i);
            postImageView.setOnClick(listUrls, i);
            linearLayout1.addView(postImageView);
            postImageView.downloadImage(listUrls, i);
        } else {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                    .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, Utils.pxToDp(5, activity));
            postImageView = new PostImageView(activity, layoutParams);
            postImageView.setPlaceholder(post, i);
            postImageView.setOnClick(listUrls, i);
            linearLayout1.addView(postImageView);
            postImageView.downloadImage(listUrls, i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == 2) {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                    .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, Utils.pxToDp(5, activity), 0);
            postImageView = new PostImageView(activity, layoutParams);
            postImageView.setPlaceholder(post, i);
            postImageView.setOnClick(listUrls, i);
            linearLayout2.addView(postImageView);
            postImageView.downloadImage(listUrls, i);
        } else {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                    .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            postImageView = new PostImageView(activity, layoutParams);
            postImageView.setPlaceholder(post, i);
            postImageView.setOnClick(listUrls, i);
            linearLayout2.addView(postImageView);
            postImageView.downloadImage(listUrls, i);
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayout1);
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2);
    break;
```

Я знаю, что функция ужасна.

```
postImageView.setPlaceholder(post, i); //метод формирования заглушки
```

Данный метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
public void setPlaceholder(Posts post, int position) {
        width = Integer.parseInt(post.getAttachmentsPhotoWidth().get(position)); //Исходный
        height = Integer.parseInt(post.getAttachmentsPhotoHeight().get(position)); //Исходный
        sideValue = post.getImageWidth().get(position); //Известна высота или ширина запрашиваемого изображения
        int destWidth = CalculateAspectRatio.getDownloadPhotoSize(width, height, sideValue).x; //таргет
        int destHeight = CalculateAspectRatio.getDownloadPhotoSize(width, height, sideValue).y; //таргет

            Picasso.with(context)
            .load(R.drawable.img_holder3)
            .noPlaceholder()
            .noFade()
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .resize(destWidth, destHeight)
            .into(this);
    }
```

Все это дело успешно тормозить скроллинг `RecyclerView`, а так же из-за потери фреймов можно увидеть как изменяется размер у `ImageView` при скроллинге, как добавляются `ImageView`.
Как избавиться от такого эффекта? Приму любые предложения по рефракторингу кода.

**UPDATE**
Инициализация `RecyclerView`:

```
private void setupRecyclerView(View view) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.container_for_home_posts);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerView);
        postAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        postAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new PostAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                postAdapter.addProgressBar();
                jsonLoader.loadPostsForFeed(countItemsLoad);
            }
        });
    }
```

Добавление новых объектов (подгружаем по 10 постов):

```
jsonLoader.setOnFeedLoadedListener(new JsonLoader.OnFeedLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeedLoaded() {
                listPosts = jsonLoader.getPostsForFeed();
                postAdapter.removeProgressBar();
                postAdapter.add(listPosts);
                postAdapter.setLoaded();
            }
        });
```

Метод `postAdapter.add();`:

```
public void add(ArrayList<Posts> listPosts) {
    int startIndex = mData.size();
    mData.addAll(startIndex, listPosts);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(startIndex, listPosts.size());
}
```

Где `Posts` - класс, хранящий данные, распарсенные из `JsonObject`.
Собственно сам `ViewHolder`:

```
    private static class ViewHolderPost extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mPostAvatar;
    ImageView mPostLike;
    TextView mPostTitle;
    TextView mPostDate;
    TextView mPostText;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public ViewHolderPost(View view) {
        super(view);
        mPostAvatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_avatar);
        mPostLike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_like);
        mPostTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        mPostDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        mPostText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.post_image_layout);
    }
}
```

Методы `OnCreateViewHolder` и `OnBindViewHolder`:

```
    //--Создание View--//
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (viewType == POST_CARD_VIEW) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_card, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderPost(view);
    } else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progres_bar, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ProgressViewHolder(view);
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

//--Метод onBind--//
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderPost) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(mData.get(position));
        this.holder = (ViewHolderPost) holder;
        addData((ViewHolderPost) holder, mData.get(position));
    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

Метод добавление данных в `view (addData())`:

```
private void addData(final PostAdapter.ViewHolderPost holder, final Posts post) {
    holder.mPostTitle.setText(post.getGroupName());
    //Todo: Изменить время публикования поста
    long dateValue = Long.valueOf(post.getDate()) * 1000L;
    Date date = new java.util.Date(dateValue);
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, в HH:mm", new Locale("ru")).format(date);
    holder.mPostDate.setText(time);

    if (!post.getText().isEmpty()) {
        holder.mPostText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mPostText.setText(post.getText());
    } else
        holder.mPostText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(post.getGroupPhoto_50())
            .into(holder.mPostAvatar);

    if (post.getIsUserLike().equals("1"))
        holder.mPostLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
    else
        holder.mPostLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);

    //--Если пост имеет вложения, нужно их отобразить--//
    if (post.getIsAttachments()) {
        holder.frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setImageToLayout(holder, post);
    } else {
        holder.frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.frameLayout.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Метод `setImageToLayout()` как раз и выполняет функции добавления`LinearLayout`:

```
private void setImageToLayout(PostAdapter.ViewHolderPost holder, Posts post) {
    //--Из массива вложений берем только изображения--//
    final ArrayList<String> listUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < post.getJsonObjectAttachments().length(); i++) {
        try {
            String t = post.getJsonObjectAttachments().getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
            if (t.equals("photo")) {
                listUrls.add(post.getURLImage(MainActivity.SCREEN_WIDTH, i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //--Добавляем полученный layout--//
    if (listUrls.get(0) != "") {
        holder.frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        holder.frameLayout.addView(Utils.getImageForPost(activity, post, listUrls, listUrls.size()));
    } else {
        holder.frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        holder.frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

`LinearLayout` с `ImageView` должен выглядеть так, как показано на изображении ниже. Количество изображений варьируется от 0 до 10.
[image: layout с изображениями должен выглядить примерно таким образом]

Comment: В каком из методов адаптера вы создаете новые вьюшки? `linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(activity);`

Comment: @metalurgus В `onBindViewHolder()` .

Comment: Тогда все очевидно - Вы создаете новый UI там, где этого делать нельзя.

Comment: @metalurgus  То есть создавать нужно в onCreate либо в теле класса viewHolder?

Comment: Именно. Точнее в onCreateViewHolder, или же в любом методе самого ViewHolder

Comment: @metalurgus Исправил, скроллинг стал плавнее, но от появления вьюшек и их ресайзе "на глазах" я так и не избавился. Виной всему видимо вложенность `LinearLayout`. Спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Из вашего кода не очень ясен контекст того как он используется. Каким образом создаются `View` для `RecyclerView`, как вы используете `ViewHolder`, вы просто показали кусок кода, который создает некий лейаут через Java код, но не то как он применяется. Сложно что-либо посоветовать, не имея понятия о том как он используется.
Сам код выглядит нормально (конечно не считая того, что вы создаете `view` без участия `xml` лейаутов), но не думаю, что проблема именно в нем, а в том как используются `View` в `RecyclerView`, как в дальнейшем обновляются и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос бы дополнен, постарался уместить все важное.

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу сдесь 2 главных причины медленной работы RecyclerView.

Во первых вложенные LinearLayout работают очень медленно, не могу представить какой именно разметки вы хотите добиться но предположу что это можно довольно просто сделать с помощью RelativeLayout(Либо GridLayoutManager). Буду рад более подробно ответить по этому пункту если вы прикрепите изображение с желаемым результатом.

Создание новых объектов сильно тормозит прокрутку. Для более эффективного использования ViewCache в RecyclerView(в приведенном примере использоваие ViewCache невозможно из за создания разной разметки для каждого элемента).

В общем есть как минимум 4 способа решения данной проблемы:

1. Универсальный, эффективный по памяти и объему вычислений, сложный в реализации - написать свой LayoutManager который будет размещать ваши динамические View как вам захочется, при этом эффективно использовать ViewCache.
2. Простой в реализации, но расходующий дополнительные ресурсы при вычислениях невидимых View. Cоздать xml файл(или написаь руками создание разметки) с разметкой где количество ImageView соответствует максимально возможному и для ImageView которые не yчавствуют в отображении элемента выставить visibility = View.GONE.
3. Немного сложнее в реализации чем 2 и расходующий доп. память на ViewCache, но не расходующий доп ресурсы на просчет невидимых View. Создать несколько разметок для разного количества ImageView(в вашем случае) который в свою очередь зависит от значения возвращаемого из getItemViewType() метода. 
   *-единственно верный по мнению @pavlofff*
4. Комбинации 3х перечисленных выше способов.

Comment: Вынужден вас огорчить, но xml-разметка это всего лишь иной способ представления виджетов на экране. При инфлейте она парсится и точно так же создаются новые объекты, по факту это еще медленее, чем создавать разметку из кода, хотя удобнее и нагляднее. Более того, View, которые имеют атрибуты GONE, INVISIBLE хотя и не отображаются в итоге, проходят все циклы создания и участвуют во всех вычислениях при формировании экрана, "скрытие" элемента никак не оптимизирует и не ускоряет работу. Для исключения виджета из текущих расчетов есть контейнер <ViewStub></ViewStub>

Comment: Очень неточный комментарий, изменения видимости очень сильно могут повлиять на производительность скроллинга списка, а Gone, Visible хоть и пробегаются по всем Callback View, но они будут участвовать далеко не всех вычислениях, в onLayout и тем более в onMeasure будет сильная разница, не говоря уже о самом onDraw

Comment: @pavlofff Да вы правы, ваша неосведомленность о том как работает RecyclerView меня и правда огорчает. Дело в том что для эффективного использования кэша все используемые лайауты должны быть одинаковые, это позволит не создавать новые объекты во врмя прокрутки(что скажется и на сборке мусора), в данном случае постоянное создание новых объектов которые невозможно переиспользовать вызывает медленную работу RecyclerView

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei см мой комментарий про View Cache

Comment: @Stepango Я в достаточной степени осведомлен о работе `RecyclerView` (можете посмотреть мои прошлые ответы по этой теме), мой комментарий относился не к механизму переиспользования айтемов, а к вашему утверждению, что при использовании xml-разметки "все View уже есть", из которого можно подумать, что они волшебным образом появляются из ниоткуда, а это не так, о чем я и донес. Для создания айтемов разного вида есть механизм через переопределение метода `getItemViewType()` все эти GONE/VISIBLE при биндинге - моветон.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei читал, что при инфлейте разметки сначала просчитывается весь интерфейс, а потом происходит скрытие, в случае с GONE еще и с перерасчетом. Статья связаная с контейнером `ViewStub`и его назначении, домой приду поищу ссылку. В общем то утверждать я не берусь, может память и подводит меня, на досуге по этой теме погуглю.

Comment: @pavlofff мне конечно очень жаль что вы думаете что View появляются из ниоткуда. Счет моветона не соглашусь с вами, подход о которм вы говорите можно использовать как один из вариантов решения, тут я с вами соглашусь. К сожалению оба подхода обладабт недостатками, ваш в итоге будет занимать больше памяти из за необходитости кэширования нескольких типов view, мой будет занимать меньший объем памяти увеличивая при этом сложность вычисления позиции элементов внутри разметки, при более простой реализации.

Comment: Не я  думаю, что они появляются из ниоткуда (странное утверждение после моего первого комментария), а из вашего ответа так можно подумать. Не надо сваливать вашу проблему недостаточно доходчиво донести мысль на того, кто читает ваш ответ, пожалуйста. Также нет никаких двух способов - есть предусмотренный разработчиком механизм и "самодеятельность" (которая иногда бывает эффективнее, но не в этом случае).

Comment: @pavlofff обязательно скиньте link, про инфлейтинг - здесь все ясно. Мне интересно про саму нагрузку при draw, можно потестить, только занят немного другим.

Comment: @pavlofff я б на вашем месте уже давно написал ответ к посту если уж вы так уверены что ваш способ единственно правильный)

Comment: У меня сейчас нет времени и ответ по списку с айтемами разного вида я писал уже раза три еще с год назад

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei да, конечно, мне самому стало интересно. Там смысл был в том, что инфлейт производится один раз, а View должно быть готово к измнению видимости, поэтому заранее просчитывается все, а потом скрывается и при изменении атрибута производится инвалидация, а не переинфлейт всей разметки. Как то так, надо выяснить этот вопрос точно

Comment: Хотел бы вас попросить воздержаться от перехода на личности в ответах, данный ресурс не одобряет подобного. В общем то я согласен с вашим ответом и тоже считаю, что програмному заполнению айтемов не место в прокручиваемых виджетах с механизмами переиспользования. Мой комментарий вызван недопониманием вашего ответа и я просто уточнил, что считал нужным, не стоит воспринимать его как личный вызов.

Comment: @Stepango Спасибо за ответ, изображение желаемой разметки разместил. Пробовал добиться такого же эффекта с помощью `GridLayout` и различных библиотек. Успехов в этом не достиг. Попробую посмотреть в сторону написания своего view.

Comment: @Вадим пробовали использовать StaggedGridLayoutManager? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514887/layoutmanager-for-recyclerview-grid-with-different-cell-width

Comment: @Stepango Посмотрел, я не уверен, но это скорее всего не то. Идеальным вариантом был вес в `LinearLayout`, а в Вашем примере вьюшки растягиваются так: мол заполни все пространство, половину или четверть. В моем же случае я указываю размер изображенйя, а дальше компановщик должен их подогнать так, что бы они в совокупности заполнили всю ширину экрана и выровнялись по высоте. Тут `LinearLayout.weight = 1.0f` выполняет всю эту работу. Пробовал так же `GridLayout` - не то. И Вы были правы, все мои беды из-за вложенности `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Stepango, Так же попробовал Ваш второй вариант из ответа. Прирост в скорости работы есть, но он довольно мал. Буду пробовать третий способ.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei К сожалению ту статью нагуглить так и не удалось, нашел [вот это](http://magicmicky.github.io/android_development/benchmark-using-traceview/), тоже весьма настораживает.

Comment: Спасибо за статью, я могу вам подробно рассказать почему изменения видимости требует больше процессов и выделения памяти при инфлейте и это разумно, это дополнительные операции особенно при Gone. Вопрос совершенно не в этом. Мы при скроле инфлейтим парента один раз, а вот нагрузка в отрисовке очень сильно зависит от видимости. В целом просто про разные вещи мы говорим, ну у я уже потестил всё, очень хотелось пощупать новый Espresso recoder, и тут попался подходящий момент, всё что писал выше только подтвердило мои слова. За статью спасибо, выводы по сути верны там и разделяют мою точку зрения.